# Trying to decrypt S/MIME file using Openssl

Tags: linux, email, openssl, encryption, smime

I am openssl Newibe.
I am trying to write a python script (calling openssl) to decrypt multiple p12 encrypted eml files but failing.

I can open them up in Thunderbird fine.

here is what i tried:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keys/pkitepki.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out file.crt.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in keys/pkitepki.p12 -nocerts -out file.key.pem
openssl smime -decrypt -in smime.p7m -recip file.crt.pem  -inkey file.key.pem
```

The error i got is :

```
Error reading S/MIME message
139955665413864:error:0D0D40D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type:asn_mime.c:451
```

What is wrong with my steps?

Answer (score 2):

The input should not be smime.p7m. it should be the email with the smime.p7m inside it. There should be email headers and a base64 encoded content.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the encrypted .p7m file attachment I got from Gmail was in DER format which is not the [OpenSSL default](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-smime.html) (default is SMIME format). So just add `-inform DER` to your OpenSSL command and see if it works.

Here was my original OpenSSL command:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in "smime.p7m" -inkey "georgie_smime.key.pem"
```

which outputted this error `Error reading S/MIME message 2147483656:error:0D0D40D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type:crypto/asn1/asn_mime.c:391:`

So just add `-inform DER`

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in "smime.p7m" -inform DER -inkey "georgie_smime.key.pem"
```

And it worked!

Also, I send the actual SMIME encrypted emails in Java using BouncyCastle if that information is useful to anyone

Answer (score 1):

Use cms instead of smime:

```
openssl cms -decrypt -in smime.p7m -recip file.crt.pem  -inkey file.key.pem
```